# Is it possible to port forward with a VLAN?

Tags: port, router, vlan

I have moved to a new place that provides an ethernet port in the wall which I have attached my router to (using dynamic IP setting). I know how to port forward with my router and it worked fine until now with a DSL connection:
My router provides 192.168.0.X IP addresses to the clients in the house. When I checked my router settings I have noticed that the default gateway and the IP address starts with 172.16 (I have connected to the router settings using 192.168.0.1), while when checking what is my external IP (through whatismyip.com for example) it shows a different IP address. I guess it means that it's a VLAN (I'm not an expert...)
When I enter the default gateway it asks for username and password which I don't have, so I guess this is the main problem. Is there a way to port forward anyways?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> the IP address starts with 172.16

That is a private IP address. Unless the port forwarding is also set up on the previous NAT router, there's no way your router can forward from public IP space.

Dual-stage forwarding is possible but requires the real public router's admin to set that up. The only alternative is via a tunnel from another public IP address (port forward from an external server/router into a VPN tunnel that you terminate).

A VLAN is nothing that can help you here.